# bootstrap input-group not grouping

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `input-group` to group together these two divs so it looks like this, but with the first item being a dropdown select.

[image]

What is looks like now

[image]

I've heard that bootstrap doesn't work using a select inside of here. Is this possible in here?

How can I get the two being next to each other like the first pic?

P.S. just look at the structure please, I remove names of stuff because proprietary.

Thanks!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3" ng-init="vm.Current = vm.interval">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.Current" ng-options="interval.set for interval in vm.intervals"></select>
  </div>
  <ng-form name="intervalsForm">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-9" ng-repeat="interval in vm.intervals" ng-show="vm.Current == interval">
      <ng-form name="singleForm">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="HH:mm:ss" name="single" id="interval" ng-model="vm.Interval" ng-pattern="/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/" ng-class="{inputError: single.interval.$error.pattern && intervalForm.interval.$dirty || single.interval.$invalid || vm.settings.$submitted && intervalForm.interval.$invalid}" required/>
      </ng-form>
    </div>
  </ng-form>
  <span class="input-error-span" ng-show="(intervalsForm.$dirty || intervalsForm.$invalid) && intervalsForm.$invalid">{{ vm.validationMessages.intervalHHmm }}:ss</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want that instead of the `@` sign the `select` will be?

Comment: Remove padding from `col-sm*` classes...

Comment: I want the @ sign in the example to be the dropdown `select`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below:

```css
.form-control .form-control {
    border:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <select></select>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Try to customize your code so it looks like this.

Comment: Can you post a link to jsbin or something with you tries? By the way, as I can see, there is an option that there will be many inputs but one select. Am I correct?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wNJyNn1Y. I had to keep a div around the `<input>` because that's where my `ng-repeats` are

Comment: Can you use a **live** code service such as http://jsbin.com with your code (**after** you tried to implement the code in my answer)